# Telerik UI Sidedrawer: how to remove gray bar from drawer-content

Tags: css, telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

How to remove this gray bar in drawer-content?

my template is:

```
<StackLayout horizzontalAlign="left" tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout" height="100%">
    <Label [text]="'Hello world'" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
</StackLayout>
<ScrollView tkMainContent>
    <StackLayout #container >
        <Image src="res://logo" stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>
        <TextField #email  keyboardType="email" [(ngModel)]="user.login"
                   autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
        <TextField #password  secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></TextField>

        <Button [text]="'Sign-in'" class="submit-button" ></Button>
        <Button [text]="'Demo'" class="demo-button" ></Button>
        <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)=openDrawer()></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: gray bar on the left side]

Answer (score 0):

That's the android status bar and for removing that I wrote the following example:

This is a statusbar that you see on top of your screen with icons of battry,clock ... .
  [image]

**Hide:**

```
let frame = require("ui/frame");                
frame.topmost().android.activity.getWindow().
getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Show:**

```
frame.topmost().android.activity.getWindow().
getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well It was not very clear but after some experiments I've found a solution - to add `margin="0"` to `tkDrawerContent`. Like this:

```
<StackLayout horizzontalAlign="left" tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout" height="100%" margin="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you have provided it looks like you have added **additional contents inside** the `<RadSideDrawer>` HTML tag.

There are two elements the `StackLayout` and the `ScrollView` (tkMainContent). The RadSideDrawer should only have two contents between its HTML tags, an element tagged with `tkDrawerContent`  and an element tagged with `tkMainContent`. Simply move the first StackLayout to the either of those elements as shown here:

```
<RadSideDrawer>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
            <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
        <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)=openDrawer()></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```